# Document functions from different modules using pdoc

Tags: python, pdoc

I've got two modules:

`first_module` containing functions `a`, `b` and `c`

`second_module` containing functions `d`, `e` and `f`

I would like to generate an **HTML** documentation using `pdoc` such that it
doesn't document both modules in whole, but rather contains only functions `b`, `e`, and `f`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73299581/can-single-pdoc-generated-pages-document-apis-spread-over-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

You can [declare `__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) in your modules as [pdoc respects it](https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc#features).

Alternatively, you can override some docstrings with a [`__pdoc__` dict](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/#overriding-docstrings-with-__pdoc__) in each module:

```
# first_module.py:
___pdoc___ = {
    'a': False,
    'c': False,
}
```

and:

```
# second_module.py:
___pdoc___ = {
    'd': False,
}
```

Comment: Note that this answer is for the module pdoc3, not for pdoc. For pdoc, the use of `__all__` is actually the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73299581/can-single-pdoc-generated-pages-document-apis-spread-over-multiple-files

Comment: @Franz Fwiw, in November 2020, while mitmproxy/pdoc was still abandoned, the question was likely referring to pdoc3.