# Can single pdoc generated pages document APIs spread over multiple files?

Tags: python, pdoc

I have a Python package which is spread over multiple files:

```
package/__init__.py
package/thing_a.py
package/thing_b.py
package/thing_c.py
package/submodule/__init__.py
package/submodule/...
```

The `thing_XXX`s break apart chunks of internal code into something that is easier for me to manage. The `__init__.py` files exports the public APIs that I want at the top-level and within each submodule:

```py
from .thing_a import the_greatest_thing
from .thing_b import even_greater_thing
from .thing_c import i_am_the_best
```

What I would like is for the documentation to display the docs for `the_greatest_thing`, `even_greater_thing` and `i_am_the_best` and provide a link to look at what's in `submodule`. What I get is a landing page which shows `thing_a`, `thing_b`, `thing_c` and `submodule` as submodules which I need to click on to get documentation. All the `thing_XXX`s are private and I use `__init__.py` to decide what gets exported - this is true also for the contents of the submodule. I would be happy to prefix them with underscores (which does prevent them showing up in the documentation) but I still can't seem to figure out how to bring all the documentation I want together.

Can this be done with pdoc? Or am I trying to do something wild and silly?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to explicitly include the in the documentation of `__init__.py` by listing them in `__all__`: https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#control-what-is-documented